# How to enable "display over other apps" feature on Unimax UMX U696CL?

Tags: settings

I have a Unimax UMX U696CL and when I got to give permission for an app to draw over, it tells me the feature has been turned off because it makes my phone run slow.

How to enable the feature on this device?

Comment: Just for additional info: according to [the manual](https://fccid.io/2ALZM-U696CL/User-Manual/User-Manual-5394824.pdf) (PDF), looks like this runs on Android 11, though it's unclear if it's Go version or not. Otherwise, the restriction may be implemented on the ROM itself, so to enable this, the user might need to flash a custom ROM that enables this feature (if it exists, or if it's even possible to flash a custom ROM)

Comment: [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4447513) + [LineageOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4358041)